# How do I create the CFErrorRef parameter required for modifying ABAddressBook via Ruby Motion

Tags: ios, ruby, abaddressbook, rubymotion

I'm trying to use Ruby Motion to add an entry to the AddressBook.
I can't figure out how to properly instantiate the CFErrorRef parameter.

```
error = nil # compiles but won't capture an error properly
# Here are my numerous attempts:
#error = Pointer.new( :object ) expected instance of Pointer of type `^{__CFError}', got `@' (TypeError)
#error = Pointer.new( '^{__CFError}' ) Can't find pointer description for type `^{__CFError}'
#error = Pointer.new( '{__CFError}' ) Can't find pointer description for type `{__CFError}'
#error = Pointer.new( '__CFError' ) Can't find pointer description for type `__CFError'
#error = Pointer.new( CFError.type ) uninitialized constant AppDelegate::CFError (NameError)
#error = Pointer.new( CFErrorRef.type ) uninitialized constant AppDelegate::CFErrorRef 
p = ABPersonCreate()
raise error[0] unless ABRecordSetValue( p, KABPersonFirstNameProperty, "Guy", error )
raise error[0] unless ABRecordSetValue( p, KABPersonLastNameProperty, "Argo", error )
ab = ABAddressBookCreate()
raise error[0] unless ABAddressBookAddRecord( ab, p, error )
raise error[0] unless ABAddressBookSave( ab, error )
NSLog( "Record successfully added." )
```

Suggestions welcome.
Guy

Comment: Are any of your calls `ABRecordSetValue()` actually failing? or are you getting to "Record successfully added."?

Comment: @Paul.s when I try his code, it's the `ABRecordSetValue(...)` is that's throwing the exception: `expected instance of Pointer of type '^{__CFError}', got `@' (TypeError)`

Comment: @DylanMarkow if I copy this exactly its works just fine :S

Comment: @Paul.s Yes, because that's with `error = nil` -- which is fine, unless there actually is an error, in which case there's no way to capture it. I tested using `error = Pointer.new(:object)` and got the exception.

Comment: I submitted a support ticket to RubyMotion on this. The docs say that RubyMotion is supposed to "automatically handle" all CoreFoundation-style APIs.

Comment: @DylanMarkow sorry I had a moment there. Curiously I can't even call something as simple as `CFSTR("test")`

Comment: Yeah, I banged my head against the wall for a couple of hours trying various variations of the above to no avail. Wasn't sure if I was missing some subtlety about how names from MFC/iOS map to Ruby. So I thought I try StackOverflow before submitting an issue. @DylanMarkow thanks for confirming that I hadn't overlooked something trivial.

Comment: @GuyArgo this is now fixed in motion 1.9. It worked for me using `error = Pointer.new(:id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to RubyMotion 1.9 includes this fix:

> - Fixed a bug in the compiler where APIs accepting pointers to
>     CoreFoundation types could not be given Pointer objects of the :object
>     type (ex. CFErrorRef*).

`sudo motion update` will get this for you.